# python parse lib does not correctly return web source code

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, lxml

```
def parser(self):
    r = requests.get(self.url)
    self.soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
```

But when I print soup I found it is different with the web source code that I really want.

For example, this is the web source code below:

```
{div class="zh-question-followers-sidebar"}
{div class="zg-gray-normal"}

{a href="/question/24269892/followers"}{strong}109141{/strong}{/a}
people focus on the questions

{/div}
```

But when I use beautifulsoup get the xml， it does not show the code that way. 
Instead, it shows like this:

```
{div class="zm-side-section"}
{div class="zm-side-section-inner zg-gray-normal" id="zh-question-side-header-wrap"}
{button class="follow-button zg-follow zg-btn-green" data-follow="q:m:button" data-id="1889792"}focus question{/button}

109143
people focus on the questions

{/div}
{/div}
```

Who can tell me why and how to get the right source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all clients are served the same page. 
You should set the user agent of your request to that of popular desktop browsers:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': '''Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1)
                            AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)  
                            Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'''}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: by adding the headers I can get the right web source code now,thanks!